# How do I encrypt my ag-grid enterprise license in React?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I acquired an ag-grid license and used it in my React application. How do I encrypt my license key to prevent client-side users from stealing my key in production and using it?

Comment: By storing it server-side and making requests to an endpoint to retrieve it when you need to.

Comment: @ObsidianAge But it is still viewable in network tab.

Answer (score 4):

You can only hide information when it is both **stored** and **utilised** server-side. Information exposed client-side can be made more *difficult* to read through means such as [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)), though the end-user will ultimately always be able to decompile it.

According to the ag-Grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-license/#setting-the-license-key) surrounding their licence key:

> "If you are distributing your product and including ag-Grid Enterprise, we realise that your license key will be visible to others. We appreciate that this is happening and just ask that you don't advertise it. Given our product is JavaScript, there is little we can do to prevent this."

While worrying that they say "*ask that you don't advertise it*", it is true; there is little they can do to prevent that, as ag-Grid is a JavaScript application.

However, you could take some measures yourself, such as storing the seed server-side, and then requesting the key through AJAX whenever you need to use it. The key will be hidden from the source code, though the request utilising the key will still be visible in the network trace. And this will also carry the overhead of the AJAX request.

So, in short, your ag-Grid licence key will **always** be visible to the public, but you can take varying degrees of precaution to make it more *difficult* for the public to work out what that key is.

Comment: `there is little we can do to prevent this.` In fact, there is nothing that they are doing to prevent this :)